# Why do people set texture node detail to 16?

Tags: geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

In following a lot of Blender tutorials, I often see people setting the level of Detail on texture nodes to 16. If you were to click and drag the Detail to the highest amount, it stops at 15.

**Is there a reason to set the detail to 16 over 15?**

[image: example of texture node with detail set to 16]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Noise Texture's Detail* slider used to top out at 16 and for some reason now it stops at 15.

Tutorials and screenshots from old versions will still show 16, and I'm sure some people still enter 16 out of habit, but there should be practically no difference between them.  In my experience it's rarely useful to go past 8.

Here are some examples at *Detail* of 2 (default), 4, and 8 from left to right.

[image]

Even though 8 is much more detailed than 4 and I've even placed it closer to the camera, you can hardly tell a difference.

You can manually enter any value you want, but the *Detail* slider can also have performance effects, so it's best to use the smallest value you can reasonably get away with.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on what result you want, higher is not offen good, take a look at the cheese I made.

1.detail=0
[image]

2.detail=15
[image]

the scale of noise only decide how big of the dot each noise have,detail means,how much subdivision of the dot.
So 16 or 15, almost no difference.

Comment: This! If you had written "look at the yellow-coloured crumpled tin foil I made", the choice would have to be different